# Word entropy / frequency in human speech

Tags: probability, entropy, frequency, information-theory

I am wondering how to best approximate the **information value** of a word $x$ in **general human speech**. By information value I literally mean its entropy:

$H(X) = \mathbb{E}_{X} [I(x)] = -\sum_{x \in \mathbb{X}} p(x) \log p(x).$

with  $p(x)$ the probability of the word $x$ occurring in general human speech (assuming nothing of the participants or their context).

But, what is the state-of-the-art in the study of $p(x)$ and its properties? Are there any known "good estimates" of $p(x)$? (at least in standard English)

I would imagine that the number of websites returned by Google or statistics of word frequency in Wikipedia can help approximate $p(x)$. But **has the statistics or computational linguistics community ever tried to estimate $p(x)$**? If so, how?

From what I understand, the security community resorts to approximations of $p(x)$ for estimating password strength (e.g. see this Cryptography thread [XKCD #936: Short complex password, or long dictionary passphrase?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase/6127#6127)). So I imagine that good sampling distributions of $p(x)$ exist and are used at least by some communities.

**Other notes:**

- According to Wikipedia, the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary) had 301,100 main entries as of 30 November, 2005. So $p(x)$ can be understood as a vector with ~300K values between 0 and 1.

Comment: This other [xkcd page](http://what-if.xkcd.com/34/) may be of interest.

Comment: I'm concerned that the question asking for repositories holding estimates of $p(x)$ seems to be straying pretty solidly toward this item in the [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) "*Questions about obtaining particular datasets are off-topic*". Further, it's not the 'statistics community' that would seek to obtain such data, but researchers in a specific area (such as speech researchers); they might tend to be users of (rather than developers of) statistical methodology.

Comment: @Glen_b I see the point on the repository. I will rephrase the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a surprisingly frustrating thing to pin down.

Shannon looked at this in one of the earliest infomation theory papers ([Shannon, 1951](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/Shannon1950.pdf)) and estimated the entropy of printed text at around 1 bit/character, using a neat 'guessing game' paradigm. In the same paper, he estimates the entropy of a word at around 12 bits. Shannon, however, used a relatively small data set[*] and it turns out that the entropy depends on many factors. @Lmorin mentioned time above, but other relevant factors include the topic (children's books have a limited vocabulary, for example), modality, context, author's style, and so on!

The general term for $P(\textrm{word})$ is a **[language model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model)** and computational linguists/natural language processing researchers spend a lot of time building them because they're very useful [**]. The models contain the per-character or per-word probability. A language model also often contains information about transitions between words. A trigram (or 3rd-order model) looks like $P(\textrm{Word}_n | \textrm{Word}_{n-1}, \textrm{Word}_{n-2}$). However, the probabilites usually aren't taken directly from the data---it's exceedingly sparse---so there are various smoothing/interpolation/back-off methods designed to produce reasonable probability distributions.

Any decent NLP textbook should have a chapter on language modelling. You might start with Chapter 6 of [Manning and Schutze's "dice book"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262133601) or Chapter 4 of [Jurafsky and Martin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131873210). However, language models are so useful that they'll also show up in contexts as diverse as speech recognition, information retrieval, and even bioinformatics. [This slide deck might](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~kathy/NLP/ClassSlides/Class3-ngrams09/ngrams.pdf) be a good place to start if you want to read more.

There's also a fair bit of literature about human language models.  Noam Chompsky famously ranted about how "the notion of 'probability of a sentence' is an entirely useless one, under any known interpretation of this term.” but a lot of people have subsequently disagreed. If you're interested in this, you may want to look for papers on 'statistical learning' (not machine learning; psychologists use the term a bit differently).

---

[*] It was the 50s and he was presumably doing most of this manually, so…fair enough!

[**] In particular, it can help resolve ambguities. Suppose you can't tell if a blob is actually a 'T' or an 'I' by itself. If one alternative produces a common word and one doesn't (Iherefore vs Therefore), it's pretty clear which one you should pick.

Answer (score 2):

The better answer I can give you:

http://books.google.com/ngrams

### Pros:

As you can see $p(x)$ is in fact $p(x,t)$, I think there's a lot of interesting (or funny) to do with this information. (what happened to parenthesis in the 17° century ? http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%5B%28%5D%2C%5B%29%5D&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

### Cons:

I don't know if you can get all that data easily.

You only have a percentage of books in which the ngrams appears, it's not really what you wanted. I think that the 2 probability are linked but the link will be hard to find without making questionnable assumptions.